# Default plugins errors after upgraded to Grails 2.2.2 from 2.2.0

Tags: grails, plugins

After upgrading from 2.2.0 to 2.2.2 I'm getting the following errors when I run grails:

```
2013-05-08 16:23:34,957 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin resources-1.1.6
Message: class path resource [web-app/file:/Users/charlie/.grails/2.2.2/projects/gpa/resources/plugins/resources-1.1.6/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
Line | Method
->>  70 | getObject              in org.grails.datastore.gorm.bean.factory.AbstractMappingContextFactoryBean
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   109 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run                    in     ''
^   680 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

I get several of those for each of the plugins.  However I get one for hibernate too which is commented out:

```
2013-05-08 16:23:35,032 [localhost-startStop-1] DEBUG support.PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource  - Could not resolve any resources for plugin hibernate-2.2.2
Message: class path resource [web-app/file:/Users/charlie/.grails/2.2.2/projects/gpa/resources/plugins/hibernate-2.2.2/grails-app/i18n/] cannot be resolved to URL because it does not exist
Line | Method
->>  70 | getObject              in org.grails.datastore.gorm.bean.factory.AbstractMappingContextFactoryBean
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   109 | postProcessBeanFactory in org.grails.datastore.gorm.plugin.support.PersistenceContextInterceptorAggregator
|   303 | innerRun . . . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run                    in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   895 | runTask . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   918 | run                    in     ''
^   680 | run . . . . . . . . .  in java.lang.Thread
```

Here is my BuildConfig.groovy:

```
plugins {
    //runtime ":hibernate:$grailsVersion"
    runtime ":jquery:1.8.3"
    runtime ":resources:1.1.6"
    compile ":lesscss-resources:1.3.3"

    // Uncomment these (or add new ones) to enable additional resources capabilities
    //runtime ":zipped-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":cached-resources:1.0"
    //runtime ":yui-minify-resources:0.1.4"

    build ":tomcat:$grailsVersion"

    //runtime ":database-migration:1.2.1"

    //compile ":cache:1.0.1"
    compile ":mongodb:1.2.0"
    compile ":mail:1.0.1"
    compile ":bcrypt:1.0"
}
```

The thing is it runs, but for some reason I can't figure out why these errors are being printed out.  Any help?  And why is it complaining about Hibernate when its commented out?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running a master application with additional plugins not mentioned in your paste thus the use of *PluginAwareResourceBundleMessageSource*.

I would recommend the following in this order :

```
rm -rf ~/.grails/2.2.2/projects/gpa
rm -rf YOUR_PROJECT_FOLDER/target
grails clean
grails refresh-dependencies
grails YOUR_ADDITIONAL_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_IF_ANY run-app
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "master application"?  How am I using additional plugins?  What settings control that?

Comment: It was a wild guess in terms of master application, not really relevant for the potential solution itself. Master application as in application that bundles some of your 'very own plugins that you wrote yourself'.

Comment: Ok.  This app, so far, doesn't bundle in any 1st party plugins, but your suggestion I think got rid of another hibernate issue.  However, it still prints those exceptions on the plugins including hibernate which is commented out.